# Webpack - React unable to load videojs css file via webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, video.js

I'm implementing `video.js` in a React web-app.

Using

```
import video.js/dist/video-js.min.css
```

it doesn't load all the css classes. Whilst if I use the following form it does.

```
require('!style-loader!css-loader!video.js/dist/video-js.min.css');
```

The latter form though triggers a `import/no-webpack-loader-syntax` eslint error.
How can I configure webpack in order for it to load the `video-js.min.css` file?

My webpack css loader config looks like this right now:

```
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
         'style-loader',
  {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      modules: true,
      importLoaders: 1,
      localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
      sourceMap: true
    }
  },
  {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
      ident: 'postcss',
      plugins: () => [
        autoprefixer()
      ],
      sourceMap: true
    }
  }
]
      }
```